# Spring Boot Errors: BeanDefinitionStoreException & FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I´m doing Spring Boot tutorial of Amigoscode. I´m at the point where he checks, whether the code is working. The classes are:

1. AppUser

```
package com.example.demo.appuser;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class AppUser implements UserDetails {
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "student_sequence",
            sequenceName = "student_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "student_sequence"
    )
    private Long id; // will be auto-generated
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AppUserRole appUserRole;
    private Boolean locked;
    private Boolean enabled;


    public AppUser(String name,
                   String username,
                   String email,
                   String password,
                   AppUserRole appUserRole,
                   Boolean locked,
                   Boolean enabled) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.appUserRole = appUserRole;
        this.locked = locked;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(appUserRole.name());
        return Collections.singletonList(authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !locked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

2. AppUserRepository

```
package com.example.demo.appuser;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, Long> {
    Optional<AppUser> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

3. AppUserRole

```
package com.example.demo.appuser;

public enum AppUserRole {
    USER,
    ADMIN
}
```

4. AppUserService

```
package com.example.demo.appuser;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AppUserService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository;
    private final static  String USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG = "Benutzer mit der Email %s nicht gefunden!";
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return appUserRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(()->
                new UsernameNotFoundException(
                        String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG, email)));
    }
}
```

5. RegistrationController

```
package com.example.demo.registration;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/registration")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationController {

    private RegistrationService registrationService;

    public String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request){
        return registrationService.register(request);
    }
}
```

6. RegistrationRequest

```
package com.example.demo.registration;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class RegistrationRequest {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String email;
    private final String password;
}
```

7. RegistrationService

```
package com.example.demo.registration;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class RegistrationService {
    public String register(RegistrationRequest request) {
        return "works";
    }
}
```

I also created a database named "registration" with PostgreSQL

My application.properties (or: application.yml):

```
# H2 properties
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

# PostgreSQL properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/registration
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=19031993
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

# Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

and my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.project-lombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Error code:

```
2023-04-20T01:07:10.425+02:00  INFO 29504 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.2 with PID 29504 (C:\Users\Kemal\OneDrive\Desktop\Provi\demo\demo\target\classes started by Kemal in C:\Users\Kemal\OneDrive\Desktop\Provi)
2023-04-20T01:07:10.428+02:00  INFO 29504 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-04-20T01:07:10.588+02:00  WARN 29504 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.example.demo.security.config.WebSecurityConfig]: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2023-04-20T01:07:10.607+02:00 ERROR 29504 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.example.demo.security.config.WebSecurityConfig]: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:524) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:497) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:304) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:297) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:196) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:398) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:283) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:211) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:48) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:923) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:334) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:514) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 21 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to fix the problems by trying to add/remove some dependencies and by changing the database & application.property settings but nothing is working. How can I fix these problems?